# Proof of Birkhoff's Theorem

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, symmetry, metric-tensor

I have a question concerning the proof of Birkhoff's theorem in Sean Carrolls book. I am stuck at the part where he shows that there are no cross-terms (in the metric) between $(a,b)$ and $(\theta, \phi)$. (Following his notation, here $(a,b)$ are the coordinates transversal to the ''foliation spheres'' and $(\theta, \phi)$ the angular coordinates in the spheres.)

He proofs it by arguing that the vector fields defined by the partial derivatives with respect to $a$, $b$ are orthogonal to those defined by the partial derivatives with respect to $\theta$, $\phi$.

Why does the second statement (about the partial derivatives) imply the absence of cross-terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we write $$ds^2=g=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu,$$
we are defining a tensor field $g$, whose action on the coordinate vector fields $\{\partial_\mu\}$ is given by 
$$g_{\mu\nu}=g(\partial_\mu,\partial_\nu).$$
To check this, recall $dx^\mu(\partial_\nu)=\delta^\mu{}_\nu$. Recall that $g$ is an inner product, so $\partial_\mu$ and $\partial_\nu$ being orthogonal means just that $g_{\mu\nu}=0$. In your case, $g_{a\theta}=g_{\theta a}=0$, for instance, as $\partial_a$ and $\partial_\theta$ are orthogonal.